# How to concatenate two columns into an autocomplete field in yii2?

Tags: yii, autocomplete, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i have a auto complete field in my view whose code is as follows

```
<?php
            $data = Members::find()
            ->select(['first_name as value', 'first_name as  label','id as id'])
            ->asArray()
            ->all();

            echo 'Name' .'<br>';
            echo AutoComplete::widget([
                 'name' => 'member_name',    
                 'clientOptions' => [
                    'source' => $data,
                    'minLength'=>'3', 
                    'autoFill'=>true,
                    'select' => new JsExpression("function( event, ui ) {
                    $('#receipt-member_id').val(ui.item.id);//#receipt-member_id is the id of hiddenInput.
                 }")],
                 ]);
            ?>
```

auto complete works correctly, it shows the first name of all the 'members'.
But there can be many guys with similar first name, so what i want is to concatenate first_name and last_name. In normal dropdowns it can be done as follows

```
<?php
    $models1 = Members::find()->all();
    $data = array();
    foreach ($models1 as $model1)
        $data[$model1->id] = $model1->first_name . ' '. $model1->last_name;

    echo $form->field($model, 'member_id')->dropDownList(
                                $data,
                                ['prompt'=>'Select...']);
?>
```

how can i do this with the autocomplete widget?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this way

```
     $data = Members::find()
        ->select(['concat(first_name,last_name) as value', 'first_name as  label','id as id'])
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
```

Comment: I you need a space between first_name and last_name:
    
    concat(first_name," ",last_name)

Answer (score 2):

If you need space between 2 fields, use this:

```
$data = Members::find()
    ->select(['concat(first_name, SPACE(1), last_name) as name', 'first_name as  label','id as id'])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

SPACE() method will generate space accord the specific number you entered, for you :D